# Dimension of a picture in a SAS report

Tags: sas, reporting, proc

How to define the dimensions of an image to be added to a report created in SAS (`ods rtf`)?
I use the following procedure:

```
ods graphics on / width=4.5in height=3.5in;
data tt1;
    image="&blabla\tt_general.jpg";
    output;
run;
proc report data=tt1 noheader nofs style={frame=void rules=none protectspecialchars=off outputwidth=80%} nowindows;
    column image;
    define image / "" display WIDTH=10 style={cellwidth=18cm};
    compute image;
    call define( _col_, "Style", "Style=[PREimage='"!!image!!"']");
    image="";
    endcomp;
run;
```

Maybe there is a better way to include an image in a report, to define the width and height?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a `preimage=` style reference in an `ods text` statement.

Example:

```
* create some arbitrary image to be shown in rtf;

%let workpath = %sysfunc(pathname(WORK));

ods listing gpath="&workpath";
ods graphics / reset imagename="carbars" outputfmt=jpg;

proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
  vbar make / group=type; 
run;

ods listing close;


ods rtf file="c:\temp\myoutput#%sysfunc(monotonic()).rtf";
ods escapechar = '^';

ods text = "^S={preimage=""&workpath.\carbars.jpg""}";   %* <---- place image in rtf;

ods rtf close;
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working when we need to import a picture created outside SAS.

Comment: How is it not working?  I had to create some image so the sample code would work. The `preimage=` should be the path to wherever your picture is.  Is the picture on the local file system, or delivered by a URL?

Comment: I created an image on R. And I resized it directly on R, since this was not possible on SAS after multiple tries. I don't know why but when I use a picture created on sas, the resizing is fine but this is not the case when I take a picture from outside. The picture is on my local file system